# A native container(.apk) which can load html files in device as an applicaiton

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to develop a web application with html5 css3 and jquery, i want to test this in real devices, i have placed all the html files in server and testing it in device with browser. is there a way i can build a native container which i can instal in device which can display my html pages in full screen like an app. for Android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing you need to use is Phonegap.

[This](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery_android/) tutorial will help you learn how to create an apk file with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile.

Phonegap can be used in numerous combinations, I will rank them by the difficulty from low to hard.

1. PhoneGap/Cordova+ jQuery Mobile -> Low difficulty

   Phonegap is what you need here, jQM is only for the UI. Still this combination is very easy to implement together and there are a lot of working examples. Phonegap servers as a wrapper for HTML5/JS/CSS and it will give you an access to mobile phone functionalists. Phonegap will be used to take a picture and jQM will be used to modifications.
2. PhoneGap/Cordova+ Sencha Touch -> Medium/Hard difficulty

   Unlike jQM Sencha Touch is a bit harder (or a lot harder) to learn, especially if you don't have a good background knowledge with javascript or don't have a license for Sencha designer tool. Go this road only if you have have enought time to learn something new.

Honorable mention goes to Rhomobile. Similar to Phonegap/Cordova but less used.

***EDIT :***

Here's an Phonegap + jQuery Mobile example: http://therockncoder.blogspot.com/2012/07/jquery-mobile-phonegap-and-camera.html, there you will find a github link for Android and iOS implementation.

**UPDATE**

You might also be interested in the open source [PropertyCross](http://propertycross.com/) project which demonstrates the same application implemented with a range of cross-platform frameworks (including Sencha, jQM and PhoneGap).